# Windows bluescreening on Chrome, WebGL, NVidia

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

This is a post for web gl developers.
Are you having nv4_disp.dll blue screen errors since you are developing web gl apps?
I have 1 or 2 every week in the last month. And I think I'm doing almost the same.
(That is , there is not any big difference into my app)

I'm using three & chrome and I promise I have this error playing with little 3D worlds (a simple plane and some lines, believe me). I have opened chrome + devtools.

Some times I have the error while I'm listening music at spotify.

I know this information can be irrelevant but maybe somebody has similar problems than me .
Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue screen errors are indication of faulty hardware or faulty graphics drivers. Chrome itself cannot be the root cause of the problem, as Chrome cannot write into kernel space where the problem occurs.

I suggest you change your hardware if you want to get rid of the problem.

You may or may not want to report to this Nvidia, but most likely they don't care about individual reports, especially if the hardware is no longer being sold.